# vuex store variable is used before it is filled in store with data from API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I am trying to get data from API through vuex.

This is an action function in store:

```
async getEpisodeFromApi({ commit }, id) {
      const data = {
        id
      };

      return await axios.get(Api.getUrl(data)).then((response) => {
        console.log("response.dat0dfgsdfa", response.data);
        commit("setEpisode", response.data);
      });
    }
```

This is an Api class (it returns the link string):

```
class Api {
  getUrl(data) {
    return "https://www.breakingbadapi.com/api/episodes/" + data.id;
  }
}

export default new Api();
```

And this is how I tried to interact with data.

```
 async beforeCreate() {
    await this.$store.dispatch(
      "getEpisodeFromApi",
      this.$route.params.episode_id
    );
  },
  async mounted() {
    const episode = this.$store.state.episode;
    episode.characters.forEach((name) => {
      this.charactersInEpisode.push(
        this.$store.characters.find((character) => character.name === name)[0]
      );
    });
}
```

But store fills state slowlier than mounted hooks begin to work. And I always get `episode` as an empty variable and `episode.characters` is undefined.

[`episode.characters` is undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJ3sD.png)

How can I fill state in store and get the data from store faster than mounted hook runs code?

Comment: Unless you use Vue 3 and can use suspense, you need to not render the component until data is ready to use

Comment: **(1)** You're incorrectly assuming `beforeCreate()` resolves before `mounted()`; Vue doesn't await the lifecycle hooks even though the functions within are awaiting calls. **(2)** `this.$store.characters` should be `this.$store.state.characters`

Answer (score 0):

You ca try to convert beforeCreated hook to method

```
methods: {
  async getData() {
    await this.$store.dispatch(
      "getEpisodeFromApi",
      this.$route.params.episode_id
    );
  },
}
```

then in mounted hook await for data:

```
async mounted() {
  await this.getData()
  const episode = this.$store.state.episode;
  episode.characters.forEach((name) => {
    this.charactersInEpisode.push(
      this.$store.characters.find((character) => character.name === name)[0]
    );
  });
}
```

Comment: thanks, but still getting an undefined

Answer (score 0):

This may be a computed property. It will be updated when the state fills with data from API:

```
computed: {
    charactersInEpisode(){
        const episode = this.$store.state.episode;
        if (!episode) return []
        return episode.characters.map((name) => {
           return this.$store.state.characters.find((character) => character.name === name)[0]
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, but still getting an undefined(

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <v-app>
        <v-content>
          <v-container>
            <h2 class="red pa-2 primary white--text">Only Limited resolved questions</h2>
            <section v-for="(item, index) in questions" :key="index">
              <li>{{index}}.- {{item }}</li>
            </section>

            <section>
              <h3>Response question 1</h3>
              <blockquote class="pa-3 secondary white--text">
                This can be done from any lifecycle hook, or a method. For the example, beforeCreate is used.
              </blockquote>
              <pre>
                    {{ $store.state.episode }}
              </pre>
            </section>

            <section>
              <h3>Response question 2</h3>
              <blockquote class="pa-3 secondary white--text">This via getter and computed property</blockquote>
              <div v-for="(item, i) in charactersInEpisode" :key="i">{{ item }}</div>
            </section>
          </v-container>
        </v-content>
      </v-app>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@2.0.0"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      // STORE (e.g. store/index.js)
      const storeTest = new Vuex.Store({
        state: {
          episode: null,
        },
        mutations: {
          setEpisode(state, payload) {
            state.episode = payload[0]; // POSSIBLE IMPROVE FROM BACKEND, SENDING OBJECT {} (NOW ARRAY [])
          },
        },
        actions: {
          async getEpisodeFromApi({ commit }, id) {
            const data = {
              id,
            };
            return await axios.get(`https://www.breakingbadapi.com/api/episodes/${data.id}`).then((response) => {
              console.log("response.dat0dfgsdfa", response.data);
              commit("setEpisode", response.data);
            });
          },
        },
        getters: {
          charactersInEpisode: (state) => {
            console.log("EXE GETTER", state);
            if (state.episode) {
              return state.episode.characters;
            } else {
              return [];
            }
          },
        },
      });

      // DATA LOCAL
      const modelCompartido = {
        questions: {
          1: "How can I fill state in store?",
          2: "get the data from store faster than mounted hook runs code?",
        },
      };
      new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data: modelCompartido,
        store: storeTest,
        mounted() {},
        async beforeCreate() {
          const episode_id = 1; // TODO: use ID for simplex example, next use/replace the params: this.$route.params.episode_id
          await this.$store.dispatch("getEpisodeFromApi", episode_id);
        },
        computed: {
          ...Vuex.mapGetters(["charactersInEpisode"]),
        },
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I limit myself only to solving the problem (resolved questions), and I eliminate the rest of the code, due to errors due to undefined variables not provided in the question.

Response question 1: How can I fill state in store?

> This can be done from any lifecycle hook, or a method. For the example, beforeCreate is used.

```
 async beforeCreate() {
      const episode_id = 1; // TODO: use ID for simplex example, next use/replace the params: this.$route.params.episode_id
      await this.$store.dispatch("getEpisodeFromApi", episode_id);
    },
```

Response question 2: get the data from store faster than mounted hook runs code?

> This is possible using Nuxt (Vue framework) through asyncData which makes the request before rendering, but if you are only using Vue it is possible to control it through getters and computed property. (among other ways); This last one is the one that I present as a solution (run code).

```
// store/index.js
  getters: {
      charactersInEpisode: (state) => {
        console.log("EXE GETTER", state);
        if (state.episode) {
          return state.episode.characters;
        } else {
          return [];
        }
      },
    },

// Component.vue
 computed: {
      ...Vuex.mapGetters(["charactersInEpisode"]),
    },
```

**NOTE:**

```
 setEpisode(state, payload) {
        state.episode = payload[0]; // POSSIBLE IMPROVE FROM BACKEND, SENDING OBJECT {} (NOW ARRAY [])
      },
```

You can run the solution and check the reactivity. I hope it will be useful